# Trouble with arrays and I/O files

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

Here is an assignment I an having trouble with. The code I have for the assignment is below. Im not sure why Im not reading in the data from the txt file. can anyone take a look at the assignment and my code and point me in the right direstion?

### Assignment

Service Calls Company Report

The OK-Service Handlers Company handles daily service calls from customers, phone calls.  The company handles folk’s problems over the phone.  The powers to be need a summary on the calls made in a given month.

The data collected is each day’s service calls that come in and is recorded in a file named SericeCalls.txt.  I will put the file out on Blackboard under Assignments.

The data indicates the type of service call made and the number of minutes that service call lasted.  The company handles several different kinds of calls and each day there will be several different entries for a given call for a given day.  The input will be two numbers per line where the first number is the type of service call and the second is the number of minutes that call lasted.  Each input line is a record of one service call.  There are 25 different types of service rendered and are numbered 1 to 25.
         For example:
    3    30              service number 3 and lasted 30 min.
    21  45              service number 21 lasted 45 min.
    6    28              service number 6 lasted 28 min.
    etc..

The company can handle up to 25 different kinds of services.  The input file is one month of data.
You are to count the number of service calls for each type of service handle and the number of minutes the call took.

- The report should have in it the following information.
- The report should have a title and headings.
- Output for each type of service call rendered,
- the total number of that service call handle for the month,
- the total number of minutes spent on that type of service call,
- the total number of service calls handle by the company,
- the average number of minutes each service type took to handle,
- the overall average a service calls took for the month.
- I also need to know if and which service call types were not used.
- Also tell me which service call took the most time to handle.
- Label all output and make it a nice readable report, table format.
- You must use arrays, pass arrays, and use functions.

### Code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

const int ROWS= 25;
const int COLS = 2;
double input;

ofstream OutFile;

//function prototype
void ReadFile(int[ROWS][2]);
void printArray(int[ROWS][2]);


int main()
{
    int ary[ROWS][2];
    //open-creates file to print to
    OutFile.open ("ServiceCallOutFile.txt");
    // Title and Heading
    OutFile << "\nMy\n";
    OutFile << "\nMonthly Service Call Report \n";
    OutFile << "Service call report generated for September 2013\n\n";
    cout << "\nMy \n";
    cout << "\nMonthly Service Call Report \n";
    cout << "Service call reprot generated for Oct. \n\n";

    // Call Function 1
    ReadFile(ary);

    // Call Function 2
    printArray(ary);
    OutFile<<"\n-----------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n-----------------------------"<<endl;

    //closes .txt file
    OutFile.close();
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

// 1)  Open and ReadFile .txt file for array
void ReadFile(int ary[ROWS][2])
{
    ifstream infile("ServiceCalls.txt");
    for(ROWS;ROWS<25;ROWS+1)
    {
        cout<<ary[ROWS][COLS];
        for (COLS;ROWS<2;COLS+1)
        {
            infile>>ary[ROWS][COLS];
        }
    }
    infile.close();
}

// 2)  Print out all the values in the array with no more than 10 numbers per output line.
void printArray(int ary[ROWS][2])
{
    OutFile<< "The numbers in the array are: \n";
    cout<< "The numbers in the array are: \n";
    for(ROWS;ROWS<25;ROWS+1)
    {
        cout<<ary[ROWS][COLS];
        for (COLS;ROWS<2;COLS+1)
        {
            OutFile<<ary[ROWS][COLS]<<" "" ";
            OutFile<<endl;
            cout<<ary[ROWS][COLS]<<" "" ";
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Input numbers from my `.txt` file.

```
17 47
10 43
20 30
4 34
15 22
21 20
3 48
17 38
18 37
12 12
5 5
4 14
8 35
17 29
21 46
2 17
```

Comment: your "for" conditions are wrong. You have no index variables to increment and reference. Go read about for loops again.

Comment: I think that this assignment might have an underlying lesson for you - learn to use a debugger - a very useful tool to be able to employ.

Comment: Learn to debug http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/debug-c-program-using-gdb/  and http://www.drpaulcarter.com/cs/debug.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have something changing in the loop to actually execute it. You just used the constants you need for the boundaries and harded coded the constant values which is a Bad Idea. The general form of a `for`-loop is

```
for (initialization; condition; advance)
```

where the `initialization` can involve the definition of a value. For example, to iterate over the values 0 to 9, you could use the loop

```
int const boundary(10);
for (int i(0); i != boundary; ++i) {
    ...
}
```

Also, your code didn't make any check if your stream is in a good state: you should always check that a value was was actually successfully read from a stream. For example:

```
if (file >> value) {
    use(value);
}
else {
    std::cout << "ERROR: failed to read a value from the file\n";
}
```